# Cordova install error

Tags: node.js, cordova

After this command :

`npm install -g cordova`

I have these errors :

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v6.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9

npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-4132-192
bb5ac\registry.npmjs.org\npm\-\npm-2.15.8.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: 9ada0f2f8a17575cf0238ffac79ebd051236bf66
npm ERR! Actual:   19abf2c8a102ec9b70c96675e09cd15a189bab3b
npm ERR! From:     http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-2.15.8.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\dev\primeng\npm-debug.log
```

Anyone knows why and how to fix it ?

Thanks by advance !

Comment: Looks like a checksum problem, I would try re downloading

Comment: Redowloading what ? And just to precise, I'm in admin mode and I've done `npm cache clean`

Comment: try `npm cache clean cordova`?

Answer (score 1):

According to [npm issue #2701](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2701) this could possibly be a result of you using an unstable version of npm, instead go for a stable version of npm, according to your logs, npm is the issue, not cordova.

Comment: Where could I get (how do I know it is or it isn't) a stable version of npm ?

Comment: @slidefizz this should help https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node if i have to put it step wise, it would be a lengthy post

Comment: I uninstalled nodejs and reinstalled LTS version but `npm install npm -g` doesn't work, same errors as cordova.